# LSTM tensorflow shape error?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I have a Class for RNN that can classify the sentences into positive or negative for sentiment analysis. Because the length of sentences are different, so I used placeholder named `text_len` to be a vector of sentence lengths in one batch when feeding the training batch data:

```
class TextRNN:
def __init__(self, hidden_size, num_classes, text_length, vocab_size,
    embed_size, l2_lambda=0.001):

    self.input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,text_length],name="input_data")
    self.output_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,num_classes],name="output_label")
    self.dropout_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name="dropout_rate")
    self.text_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

    with tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size,embed_size],-1.0,1.0),trainable=True,name="W")
        self.word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_data)

    with tf.name_scope("hidden"):
        lstm_fw_cell=rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)
        lstm_bw_cell=rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)
        lstm_fw_cell=rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_fw_cell,output_keep_prob=self.dropout_rate)
        lstm_bw_cell=rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_bw_cell,output_keep_prob=self.dropout_rate)
        outputs,_=tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell,lstm_bw_cell,inputs=self.word_embeddings,sequence_length=self.text_len,dtype=tf.float32)
```

In my main method:

```
for ex in range(1,3):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        sess = tf.Session()
        with sess.as_default():
            rnn = TextRNN(
            hidden_size=100,
            num_classes=2,
            text_length=160,
            vocab_size=len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_),
            embed_size=100,
            l2_lambda=0.001)

            global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
            grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(rnn.loss)
            train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars,global_step=global_step)

            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            vocabulary = vocab_processor.vocabulary_

            initW = None
            initW = loadw2v.convert_glove(vocabulary, pretrained_embeddings, 100)
            sess.run(rnn.W.assign(initW))


            #training step
            def train_step(x_batch, y_batch, start_index, end_index):
                feed_dict = {rnn.input_data:x_batch,rnn.output_label:y_batch,rnn.dropout_rate:0.5,rnn.text_len:x_train_len[start_index:end_index]}
                _, step, loss, test = sess.run([train_op, global_step, rnn.loss, rnn.text_len], feed_dict)
```

because I want to feed a vector of sequence length into RNN model, so there is a `rnn.text_len:x_train_len[start_index:end_index]` when using `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`, `x_train_len[start_index:end_index]` is a vector that saves the length of sequence, start_index is the index of batch start, end_index is the index of batch end. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: seq_lens(45) > input.dims(1)
     [[Node: hidden/bidirectional_rnn/bw/ReverseSequence = ReverseSequence[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlen=DT_INT32, batch_dim=0, seq_dim=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding/embedding_lookup, _arg_Placeholder_0_0)]]
```

I don't understand this error, any idea?

Comment: Provide a full script to reproduce